# What is the best way to pass and keep path data to a form in Node.js w/ Express?

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I've got a form that is accessed either directly at

```
router.get('addform'...)
```

but it also support pre-populating some fields through params, so I have

```
router.get('/addtime/:user?/:role?/:projectId?', ...
```

In the second version I throw in some logic to extract each param into res.locals, and in my pug file I check to see if they are filled in. I do this so that users can bookmark a shortcut to the form with their username, role, and projectID potentially saved in (I don't do this with user accounts because roles can change based on the task, and some people will enter time for their team).

The issue I'm running into is when I post the form. I want the data to save, and to have the user redirected back to the same path, but I also want to pass the results of the saved form to show up on the same page.

If I save the currentPath to res.locals and redirect, I lose the result of the form submission, and if render the view again, it doesn't extract the params.

I suspect I could extract the params in pug with some JS, or pass all the data via querystring, but it doesn't feel like that's the 'right' way to do it. Any thoughts on the best approach?

Comment: If you really don't want the page to reload (thus emptying the form), then one option is to just submit the form in your page via Ajax and not an actual form post.  Then, the existing page will just stay where it was like it was with the content it had in it.

Comment: Or, upon form post, take the form data and pass it to your renderer so it will populate that data back into the form.  If you design the data structure right that the renderer is expecting, you should be able to use the same data structure from the form post as what you pass to the rendered when you have `router.get('/addtime/:user?/:role?/:projectId?', ...`).  In one case, the data comes from the form post.  In the other case, the data comes from the URL parsing.